# How Node Js perform real time checking on database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis

In node.js how they perform database check for real time notificaion?

Is it using any framework like "ondatabaseupdate"'s function?
Or just use setInterval at node js every second to perform check db?

I'm quite new on node.js i'm not sure im gonna to use 
redis to store data or mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called message queuing. Redis has an inbuilt PubSub adapter that can be used for this.

The basic idea is that clients can publish (emit) events on a defined channel, and other clients can subscribe (listen) to whatever is coming in. The listener could be routing incoming data to a pool of workers, which, for example, write your data in a database.

The Redis site has an [article about pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) which is quite detailed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,just a question to ask, is it mostly all node.js user majority they using redis to store their data?what if I really use mySql to store my data, if I use set-interval to perform real time check per second, will it be heavy to my server?tq very much....& sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Node and Redis is a combination that seems to work well in many cases. If your data isn't suited for the way Redis works, you should stick to MySQL. If you query your database once a second, unless you receive megabytes of data each time, that will be an easy job for either database. So choose the one that better suits your data.